# java.lang.NullPointerException on AsyncTask android studio to Retrofit Rest API

Tags: java, android, rest, android-asynctask, cassandra

I am trying to send data from an Android Mobile App to Retrofit Rest API.

I took reference from this:

The Android APP 
https://github.com/MiraLak/AccelerometerAndroidApp

Retrofit Rest API (server, handles the data sent from the android app) 
https://github.com/MiraLak/accelerometer-rest-to-cassandra

the server then forwards the data to Cassandra.

i did some modification in the android app to send my custom data (battery info) instead of the accelerometer data as in the project i took as template.

Here is my `SendAccelerationAsyncTask`  Class

```
 private class SendAccelerationAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Collection, Void, Void> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Collection... params) {
            try {
                SampleData training = new SampleData();
                training.setCollection(params[0]);
                cassandraRestApi.sendTrainingAccelerationValues(training);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
}
```

My problem is that when i try to send to data, the AsyncTask crashes with error:

```
04-13 08:55:43.120 4750-4818/com.miralak.basicaccelerometer W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-13 08:55:43.121 4750-4818/com.miralak.basicaccelerometer W/System.err:     at com.miralak.basicaccelerometer.activity.CollectDataActivity$SendAccelerationAsyncTask.doInBackground(CollectDataActivity.java:459)
04-13 08:55:43.122 4750-4818/com.miralak.basicaccelerometer W/System.err:     at com.miralak.basicaccelerometer.activity.CollectDataActivity$SendAccelerationAsyncTask.doInBackground(CollectDataActivity.java:422)
04-13 08:55:43.122 4750-4818/com.miralak.basicaccelerometer W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-13 08:55:43.123 4750-4818/com.miralak.basicaccelerometer W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-13 08:55:43.123 4750-4818/com.miralak.basicaccelerometer W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-13 08:55:43.123 4750-4818/com.miralak.basicaccelerometer W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-13 08:55:43.123 4750-4818/com.miralak.basicaccelerometer W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-13 08:55:43.123 4750-4818/com.miralak.basicaccelerometer W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
```

I checked and confirmed that the variable being send is not null 
but I am getting null pointer exception?

Thanks

**update**

NOTE: 
line 459 is  `cassandraRestApi.sendTrainingAccelerationValues(training);`

i checked the values in `training` by:

```
Log.v("test", "" + training.getCollection().getStatus());
Log.v("test", "" + training.getCollection().getTechnology());
Log.v("test", "" + training.getCollection().getTemperature());
```

and so on..

here is the `sendTrainingAccelerationValues` method:

```
public interface CassandraRestApi {
    @POST("/test")
    Response sendTrainingAccelerationValues(@Body SampleData testing);
}
```

Comment: Where is your `cassandraRestApi` being initialised? Coudl you post the code at line number 459. I realise it's already there but I can't see the line  numbers

Comment: which line is 459 here ?

Comment: this is line 459: cassandraRestApi.sendTrainingAccelerationValues(training);

i already check if `training` has values by: 
  Log.v("test", "" + training.getCollection().getStatus());
  Log.v("test", "" + training.getCollection().getTechnology());
 and so on.. 
 i can post the `sendTrainingAccelerationValues` method if needed!

Comment: So `cassandraRestApi` is null.

Comment: @MikeM. i tested `cassandraRestApi` for null, and its not null!

Comment: Then use the stack trace, log prints, debugger, etc., to figure out what is null. It's a basic programming skill that you need to learn sooner or later. We can't really debug your app for you, and the given info is not enough for a definite answer.